# Issue with DataGridView.Rows.Count

Tags: c#, ms-access, data-binding, datagridview, ado.net

I have populated a Datagridview from Access table by using following approch:

```
using (OleDbDataAdapter a = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn))
{
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    a.Fill(t);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
}
```

I am sure that I have 100 rows in my original table in Ms Access Database but I am getting 101 rows when I try to count the rows number in DataGridView and populate on on a label(NumofRows)

```
NumofRows.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
```

This make a big deal when I try to export dataGridView Values to any other format!.Can you please let me know why I dealing with this?

Comment: what does the query look like.. are you doing any odd Joins that may yield incorrect results..? show uswhat the sqlQuery looks like

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that there are not 101 rows?

Comment: Here is the Query : `string sqlQuery = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", tdbName);`

Comment: And I am 100% positive I have 100 rows in Table.

Comment: never ever use `SELECT * FROM`, it will be vulnerable, use Parameterized queries. even String.Format() is also not a good choice to pass the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the source data and the SqlQuery, we can't say for sure.

My suspicion is, there is a header row either in your data, or in your execution that is being rendered.

The best way to check is to look at the rendered data and compare it to your stored data and see what's there.

It could also be a 0 index miscommunication. I.E. either in your data or your loop you are seeing 101 where 100 is.

If we get more information, we can take a better guess.

Comment: See what you uncover by comparing the live data. If your first row is your titles/headers, that would make it easy. I.E. Row[0] = "Title,Date" etc...

Comment: If that isn't it, your best bet is to look for duplicates

Comment: There is no duplicate row in datagridview